# Rank elements in a data frame while keeping index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the following formula to gather the top 20 elements for each row in a data frame. It works great but it is dropping the index column from the df_returns but I'd like to keep them. I was using dates as the index in the df_returns data frame and I'd like to have the same dates corresponding to the new data in the df_rank data frame.

```
df_rank = pd.DataFrame({n: df_returns.T[col].nlargest(21).index.tolist() for n, col in enumerate(df_returns.T)}).T
```

For example, let's say I was wanting to get the top 3 from the following data frame:

```
           A   B   C   D   E
1/1/2014   5   4   6   8   1
2/1/2014   2   1   6   3   1
3/1/2014   8   2   3   5   1
```

The results I'm getting currently are:

```
0   D   C   A
1   C   D   A
2   A   D   C
```

The results I'd like to get are:

```
1/1/2014   D   C   A
2/1/2014   C   D   A
3/1/2014   A   D   C
```

Comment: Could you attach your dataframe?

Comment: would you like the df_rank dataframe or the df_returns dataframe?

Comment: Both, original and expecting output

Comment: I've included an example.

Comment: With simple solution you could use `set_index`, like `df_rank.set_index(df_returns.index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set index of your new dataframe from original one:

```
df_rank.set_index(df_returns.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a function to each row of a data frame, `apply` is often your best bet (I've rewritten your function a bit too):

```
d.apply(lambda r: r.sort_values(ascending = False)[0:3].index.tolist(), axis=1)

Out[88]:
1/1/2014    [D, C, A]
2/1/2014    [C, D, A]
3/1/2014    [A, D, C]
```